# Find position of first letter in string

Tags: php, regex

How would I find the position of the first occurance of a letter (a-z) case insensitive using regex?

```
$string = "(232) ABC";
```

I want to see the number 7 returned as A is in position 7

I have found the following but it doesn't seem to work for all string:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i", strtolower($tel_current), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

E.g. it doesn't work for the following:

```
"(520) 626-1855 kafds r";
```

I just get an empty array.

Comment: REmove the `^` and `$` from your regex.

Comment: Why not use `strpos()`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard- I know of no way to match on letters only using strpos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
<?php
preg_match('/[a-z]+/i', '|Tel: (520) 626-1855 kafds r', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_export($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Tel',
    1 => 1,
  ),
)
```

To find the position of  the string `kafds r`,

```
<?php
preg_match('/(?<=\d )\w+ \w+/i', '|Tel: (520) 626-1855 kafds r', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_export($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'kafds r',
    1 => 21,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Maybe he wants to get the position of `kafds r`, not `Tel`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Sorry, my initial post was wrong with the example that had "|Tel:"- that shouldn't have been there. I have removed it. Thanks again